# Where can I find homeless people to beat up?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I've searched the map three times over, but I can't find the last homeless person I need to beat up.

**What are the locations of all the homeless people?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably missing this one since he is hardest to find.He is marked by red circle on the image.

[image]

Go to the bus stop(**near southpark sign**),then go left over the road,where you will see **girl on the bench**,you will see few trees near her.Now if you go behind those trees you will see that there is a hidden path through the fence,follow the mud road and you will find them.

Others can be found :

- To the right of the **kennys house**,near a car.
- In the back of a **U-stop** truck(parked in front of U-STORE-IT).
- 4 of them are in the **sewers**,you can access them after the abduction.

Or just watch the video to see all 7 exact locations.

Comment: Actually I was missing the U-stop one; I didn't realize you can jump into the truck.  However, this question was meant to be more general - could you add more details about where to find the others?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft the 4 that aren't specifically enumerated are all in the sewers. Which are... kind of a maze and a bit tough to map specifically, and screenshots without a complete map won't be all that helpful I suspect.

Comment: Yes,it would just be confusing trying to explain the sewers pathway with words.But the sewers aren't that much of a labyrinth since most of the paths are blocked and you are forced to go in pre-determined path,also you will probably have few more quests down there so you will eventually end up exploring all of the sewers.

Comment: I didn't find one of the sewer-hobos until near the end of the game, because I didn't realize you could walk past a pipe that looked like it's impassable.  I'm sure I'm not the only one, so yes, even just directions will surely help someone.

Comment: Actually I got something better xD